# Android Camera Taken Picture is not saving to sd card

Tags: android, eclipse, android-camera, save-image

I have developed a simple android application in Eclipse for Opening camera and taking photo and saving this to Sdcard but when i start camera and take picture and when try to save my application got error that Application ha stopped unfortunately .Is Kindly Help me is there any issue in my code file
here is my code for saving and taking picture from camera.

```
package cam.cam.pkg;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CAMActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private Button button_1;
    public int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;
    private ImageView image_view;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

         image_view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.result);
         button_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            try {
                // We need to recyle unused bitmaps
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    bitmap.recycle();
                }
                InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                        data.getData());
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
                stream.close();
                image_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Kindly Guide me what exactly I am missing in my code or any other way to get out of this problem

**Update**

Here is My Manifest File Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="cam.cam.pkg"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".CAMActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

But cam is Not Still saving Image to gallery and application Stooped unfortunately

Sir Here IS My Error Log

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument not valid)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4282)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4197)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog.open(MessageDialog.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.dialogs.InternalErrorDialog.open(InternalErrorDialog.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.openQuestionDialog(IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.handleException(IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.access$0(IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler$1.runInUIThread(IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob$1.run(UIJob.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument not valid
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4263)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4197)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4168)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.drawImage(GC.java:958)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.drawImage(GC.java:943)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.ImageOverlay.paint(ImageOverlay.java:214)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.LayoutCanvas.onPaint(LayoutCanvas.java:729)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.LayoutCanvas.access$0(LayoutCanvas.java:723)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.LayoutCanvas$1.paintControl(LayoutCanvas.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.WM_PAINT(Composite.java:1564)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4585)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4985)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.RedrawWindow(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.update(Control.java:4380)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.update(Display.java:4846)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.LegacyAnimationFeedback.renderStep(LegacyAnimationFeedback.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.AnimationEngine.updateDisplay(AnimationEngine.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.AnimationEngine$1.run(AnimationEngine.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UILockListener.doPendingWork(UILockListener.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer$3.run(UISynchronizer.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    ... 35 more
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code::::

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            try {
            image_view.setImageUri(Uri.parse(data.getDataString()));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

**Updated::::**
Add the below permissions n manifeast file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Comment: Sir Still  Same Problem Occurred

Comment: No Sir I added Nothing In manifest File Kindly tell me What to add and where to add ?

Comment: Sir No Effect Still Same Error

Comment: Yes I added all as U provided copy and paste to my manifest file but same error is Occuring

Comment: [2012-05-25 11:36:19 - Unexpected error while launching logcat. Try reselecting the device.] device not found
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device not found
 at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.setDevice(AdbHelper.java:752)
 at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:373)
 at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:397)
 at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatReceiver$1.run(LogCatReceiver.java:102)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: This is Logcat 05-25 17:06:47.568: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2976)

Comment: Sir I have Pasted mY error Log In Question Please chek this Now

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public class Camera extends Activity 
  {
 private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
 private String selectedImagePath;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) 
        { 
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);
            Random randomGenerator = new Random();randomGenerator.nextInt();
            String newimagename=randomGenerator.toString()+".jpg";
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                    + File.separator + newimagename);
            try {
                f.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //write the bytes in file

            try {
                fo = new FileOutputStream(f.getAbsoluteFile());
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                uri=f.getAbsolutePath(); 
    //this is the url that where you are saved the image
      }



  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code set. It works for me...

With in the `onActivityResult` method call following code set.

```
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(90);

    int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    int height = bitmap.getHeight();

    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);

    // Display the captured image oon your screen
    capturedImageView.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);

    getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

    File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    if (pictureFile == null){
        Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");
        return;
    }

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        fos.write(data);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Matrix part is not relevant to your problem directly. Then you will need following two methods also.

```
private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
      return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(imagesSavingSubfolderPath);

    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            return null;
        }
    }

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}
```

Be careful with the variable name I have given. :-)

In the Manifest don't forget to give following permission too

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

Comment: Sir I have show up my manifest file code but still cam is not working

Comment: Where is your Camera permission? `uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"`

Comment: @user1397781 also you might want this too in your Manifest file `uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"`

Comment: Sir No Effect By also adding camera Persmission Too

Comment: @user1397781 then if you are getting any error, please post the error log here.

Comment: Sir I am Testing camera On emulator But This is still not working with also "android.hardware.camera" permissions added in manifest File

Comment: @user1397781 at least are you getting Camera surface view in your Emulator? Would you able to get a photo?

Comment: Yes I am Showing camera Surface and also capture button but when I press tick to save Image It Stopped the application Unfor...

Comment: @user1397781 what is the error or the exception you get in your Logcat?

Comment: 05-25 16:59:15.160: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2976)

Comment: Sir this is Error Log generated

Answer (score 0):

```
if (requestCode == CAMERA) {
                    Log.d("log", " request code camera " + requestCode);
                    final File file = getTempFile(this);
                    try {
                        selImagePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                        m_bmOCRBitmap = Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),
                                Uri.fromFile(file));
                        img_pht.setImageBitmap(m_bmOCRBitmap);
                        hideMenu();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                } 


try this code...
```